# Centered Shadow Using Uno.Platform ElevatedView

Tags: xaml, uno-platform

I can't center the shadow provided by `<toolkit:ElevatedView>` around the contained object. By default the shadow falls to the lower right corner. I've tried shifting with margins as well as RenderTransform, but can't find a good way to move the shadow.

What I have:

```
<toolkit:ElevatedView x:Name="Shadow1" Elevation="25" ShadowColor="Gray" CornerRadius="20" Background="Transparent">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
      <TranslateTransform X="20" Y="20"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
  
    ...stuff
  
  </Grid>
</toolkit:ElevatedView>
```

This kind of works but screws up the grid corner radius because it is being shifted beyond its max width. Is there a way to simply move the shadow location instead of trying to shift the content inside the shadow?

Answer (score 0):

As of Uno Platform 3.11, the `ElevatedView` Control does not support changing the orientation of the shadow, only the elevation.

You may want to open an enhancement request on the Uno Platform GitHub repository.